# Did the writer mention that 2 Tomoe Sharingan can instantly awaken into Mangekyou Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

As you can see on the title, what I recall correctly is, every Mangekyou Sharingan user must have awoken the 3 Tomoe Sharingan before awakening the Mangekyou. For example: Uchiha Sasuke, Uchiha Itachi, Uchiha Madara, and Uchiha Fugaku. All of these users awoke their 3 Tomoe Sharingan and then later on awoke Mangekyou Sharingan.

But just now I found a small loop hole: Obito and Kakashi. Before they awaken their Mangekyou Sharingan, their previous Sharingan only has **2 Tomoe**. Here is the **[clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIltpFAFNmo)** that I found.

As you can see below, both of their eyes only have 2 Tomoe before Kakashi kills Rin.

[image]
[image]

But after Kakashi kills Rin, they instantly skip the 3 Tomoe Sharingan and jump straight to awakening the Mangekyou.

[image]

**How can they can skip the 3 Tomoe and instantly awaken the Mangekyou? Is this a small detail that the writer didn't explain?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3 tomoe state wasn't skipped. At 1:16 in the video you can see the 3 tomoe sharingan.

[image]

This progression is also shown in the respective manga page.

[image]